# NoClassDefFoundError problems

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

i have this error while executing my android application:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Syntax
at com.example.testtvprg.QueryDBpedia.doInBackground(QueryDBpedia.java:56)
at com.example.testtvprg.QueryDBpedia.doInBackground(QueryDBpedia.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

this is my AsyncTask class: i try to connect to DBpedia and send a query with Jena Api, and then i call this class on My MainActivity class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Syntax;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;


 public class QueryDBpedia extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void>{ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... keyword) {
    try{
            String sparqlQuery="PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n" + 
        "SELECT DISTINCT ?film_URI \n" +
        "WHERE {\n" +
        "?film_URI rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film> . \n" +
        "} Limit 10" ;
    String service=  "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
    Query qur=QueryFactory.create(sparqlQuery,Syntax.syntaxARQ);
    QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(service,qur );
    ResultSet results = ResultSetFactory.copyResults( exec.execSelect() );

    while ( results.hasNext() ) {
         RDFNode s= results.next().get( "resource" );
         list.add(s.toString());
                }

    }  catch (Exception  e) {
        Log.e("Jena", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
} }
```

and below the function where i call the asyncTask class:

```
public void ExplorButton( View v) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException 
    {   
        QueryDBpedia qdb=   new  QueryDBpedia();
        qdb.execute("");

    }
```

i don't understand where is the problem. Please help me.

Comment: Where is your code!! paste your code

Comment: in your library the class "com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Syntax" is mising...

Comment: Please who can help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

**com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Syntax** is missing in your package , Try posting the code , will you .

Comment: ,asad.qazi the library is not missing, it exists in my package. i edit the question and i put my code

Comment: Well, it may be there at *compile* time, but it surely can not be found at runtime, otherwise you'd not get the error *Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: **com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Syntax***